# Pequeno bug no dashboard do perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Apenas reportando um "bug" na página do perfil pessoal.

O bloco "Novo privilégio" aparece com conteúdo desalinhado.

Browser: Google Chrome last release.

SO: Windows 8.1 pro

*Não testei em outros browsers ou SO.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O texto precisa ser bem mais curto. O atual é "Ver contagem de votos (a favor/contra); cartão de usuário torna-se expansível". Sugestões?

Comment: "Ver contagem de votos" já é suficiente,eu acho.

Comment: Como está em inglês @bfavaretto?

Answer (score 2):

Como o bfavaretto disse, o texto precisa ser mais curto. O original, em inglês, é:

> see votes, expandable usercard

Bem mais curto que o nosso:

> Ver contagem de votos (a favor/contra); cartão de usuário torna-se expansível

A sugestão "Ver a contagem de votos" do Math parece razoável. Tentei adicionar a parte sobre o usercard (usando a tradução "ficha do usuário" que está na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)) mas sempre ultrapassa o tamanho.

Acho melhor deixar "Ver a contagem de votos" mesmo

Comment: Acho que eu fui o responsável por deixar gigante, antes era mais curto :S

Comment: @bfavaretto Aqui no SOpt nós não procuramos culpados, mas sim soluções (PS: A responsabilidade é toda sua)

Comment: valeu! vi hoje que foi corrigido! agora sim! ficou bom! obrigado!